How to know if a query returns a scalar?
Is there a way to know whether a query returns a scalar or not without parsing the statement? For example, given a string like, which could be:
SELECT * FROM tbl

And may or may not return a scalar (the table could potentially have one row / one column).
Is there some command similar to EXPLAIN or DESCRIBE that can tell me this? Or is this not necessary available at parsing?

I suppose one way might be just to wrap it in SELECT ($sql) LIMIT 1 to ensure it's a scalar subselect and handle that with a try/catch block in the programming language calling the SQL. Is there a better option?

Are you doing this from a programming language?  If you're doing a query from an application using a library, the query results will ALWAYS be a list of records.  Even if there is only one record, it will be a list containing one row.  The result doesn't have to be treated differently.

This is to prevent, say, a user entering something that might return a billion rows. I need to make sure, before runtime, that it only returns one (or zero) row.

The short answer is No. how would the system know what table this will reach, and what columns/rows there would be without parsing? that would be magic.

@tinazmu the db may parse it, I'm just saying the front-end wouldn't parse it. Would the SELECT (...) approach work?

SELECT ($sql) doesn't change anything.  It's still a list of rows.  Every query returns a list of rows.  Note that your SQL library has the concept of a cursor, so you can read a small subset of the rows at a time, without transferring a billion rows at once.

@TimRoberts oh you're correct, it just enforces it's a single column (not a single row). I suppose then doing SELECT ($sql) LIMIT 1 would be a good substitute then?

Some providers have the option to limit the number of rows received. For example, in ADO.NET you can pass the CommandBehavior.SingleRow parameter.

Substitute for what?  It is extraordinarily dangerous to execute SQL statements directly from user input.  You need to control how the statement is put together, so some smart aleck user doesn't do SELECT 1; DELETE * FROM tbl;.

@TimRoberts that's ok actually. It's an admin user who 'owns' the database, and they only have READ access to a single table.

A single row and a single column doesn't ensures that there won't be a spike of resources into answering that query. That single value may still be CPU or IO very expensive to calculate.

@Alejandro that's ok...even something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl could take a few hours/days/whatever to do on a large table. This is more to prevent network-transfer issues.

Sounds like you just need to limit the maximum network load using some kind of rate limiter/traffic shaper. Parsing the SQL is probably the wrong tool here. How would you even know how much data it is until it's read, it might be 10 rows of 2Gb blobs or 100m rows of 1-byte bools?

@Charlieface any idea/examples of what a possible rate-limiter/traffic shaper would be here? Do most libraries have this or it'd be outside the sql client?

There's no way to determine what a query will return before it is executed, and if you're using SELECT *, you've already screwed yourself. If you want a specific number of columns returned, you should avoid using * like the plague. Specify the column name(s), and you know exactly how many columns will be returned. If you want a specific number of rows, use the WHERE clause to limit the results, and use TOP or LIMIT to narrow those results down to the max number of rows you want.

No this would be a feature on an external device such as a firewall

A nonelegant solution is to run
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 2

and count both the fields and the records. However, that's doing some parsing even if it will never yield you a billion rows. You can pair this with a caching system, where you would cache by table and fields and of course, if the field list contains at least two fields, then you can dismiss it as nonscalar without any kind of parsing.
A more elegant (and more complex) solution would be to create a list of FDs and CFDs as well as ARs (see http://studia.ubbcluj.ro/download/pdf/881.pdf particularly the article titled "FINDING, MANAGING AND ENFORCING CFDS AND ARS
VIA A SEMI-AUTOMATIC LEARNING STRATEGY") and check your where and group by criteria against this lattice.
For example, if you have an FD of
S -> D
and you have a query of
select somefield
from sometable
where D = 'somevalue'
group by S

then we know for sure that any S uniquely identifies a single D and the where clause guarantees you will have a single record the most.
Conditional functional dependencies are of the form of
c => S -> D
so an example matching this would look like
select somefield
from sometable
where c and D = 'somevalue'
group by S

where c is a condition, it could be any logical expression.
Surely, your queries may combine FDs and CFDs, but if you properly implement the logic that rests on the relational algebra of implications of having FDs and CFDs, you can then reliably determine whether your query may have multiple records or not.
So, the elegant solution would look like this:

having knowledge about FD and CFD criterias
checking the where, on and group by clauses to see whether we can guarantee there will be no more records than one
being aware of the number of fields each table has for the case when the wildcard of select * is being used

Surely, you can combine multiple table into a single query by joining or unioning them, but given the fact that queries are closures upon relations and, as a consequence each query is a table even if the resulting relation is not in your schema, you can apply the implication of known FDs and CFDs on your joined queries too.
